# form post dont save in BD select menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I completed a form and sent it but for a strange reason it does not save the region field

1- view

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :región %>
    <%= select_tag(:region, options_for_select([['Lisbon', 'lisbon'], ['Madrid', 'madrid']]),:required => true, :include_blank => '-- Seleccione una Región --',id: :question_region) %>

  </div>
```

2-

```
Started POST "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-04-23 16:02:32 -0400
Processing by QuestionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"71bcceUQeh6esxxsU/9qPyjWWsNgOLZXuWOMWJ8JvwlQ7Mt6uY56as1WBTzyOtUKJBf/drsJBtYh1HSu+V3KTg==", "question"=>{"name"=>"marcelo", "email"=>"xxxx@gmail.com", "content"=>"Esto es un mensaje de prueba"}, "region"=>"lisbon", "commit"=>"Ingrese su pregunta"}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.3ms)  INSERT INTO `questions` (`name`, `email`, `content`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('marcelo ', 'xxxx@gmail.com', 'Esto es un mensaje de prueba', '2019-04-23 20:02:32', '2019-04-23 20:02:32')
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/questions/10
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
```

what do I do to include region in the " insert into"

Comment: please add the code of the create action to the question and any other code that might be relevant (model, rest of the controller, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If region is an attribute of the Question model, then you should use `form.select` instead of `select_tag` so that the region is included in the question's parameter hash:

```
<%= form.label :región %> <%= form.select(:region, options_for_select([['Lisbon', 'lisbon'], ['Madrid', 'madrid']]), :required => true, :include_blank => '-- Seleccione una Región --', id: :question_region) %>
```

Comment: thanks your solution worked and I can save the field